# GoLand IDE debug where several .go files must be compiled?

Tags: goland

I have several .go files in a folder and functions can be referenced when I run them as "go run ." so all the .go files get compiled.

But I don't know how to do this inside the GoLand IDE. I'd especially like to be able to debug this code so running inside the GoLand IDE would be nice.

main2.go contains
`func main2()`

Which I can reference from main.go with
`main2()`

This works perfectly when run as "go run ." or "go run *.go" but "go run main.go" doesn't compile main2.go so the reference to main2() is not resolved and causes

`./main.go:29:2: undefined: main2`

And the GoLand IDE gets the same error when I try to run main.go. I guess I just don't know how to tell the GoLand IDE to compile all the .go files before linking and execution...

Any suggestions are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compile these files by clicking on the directory name inside Project View and selecting *Run > go build projectName*. Or select *Debug > go build projectName*.

[image]